# no me deja crear en entitty framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo un problema al crear una nueva sede sede=edificio.

Al presionar el botón de guardar en la vista de crear me da el siguiente error:

> Entities in 'Entities.RRHH_SEDE' participate in the
>   'FK_RRHH_MUNICIPIO' relationship. 0 related 'RRHH_MUNICIPIO' were
>   found. 1 'RRHH_MUNICIPIO' is expected

Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: RRHH_SEDE/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(mod.RRHH_SEDEModel collection)
{
    try
    {
        // TODO: Add update logic here
        ent.RRHH_SEDE entidad = Mapper.Map<mod.RRHH_SEDEModel, ent.RRHH_SEDE>(collection);
        db.Modificar(entidad);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

He agregado los campos de municipio en el model pero no me deja guardar.

---

```
public class RRHH_SEDEModel 
{ 
    public short COD_SEDE { get; set; }
    public string NOMBRE { get; set; } 
    public string UBICACION { get; set; } 
    public virtual RRHH_MUNICIPIO RRHH_MUNICIPIO { get; set; } 
    public virtual SEG_ESTADO SEG_ESTADO { get; set; }    
 }
```

ese es mi model

Comment: Hola. Puedes poner la definición de las clases de RRHH_SEDE y RRHH_MUNICIPIO? porque básicamente ese error es que no has establecido un municipio para la sede.

Comment: este es mi model de sede  public class RRHH_SEDEModel
    {

        public short COD_SEDE { get; set; }
        public string NOMBRE { get; set; }
        public string UBICACION { get; set; }
       // public virtual ICollection<RRHH_AREA> RRHH_AREA { get; set; }
        public virtual RRHH_MUNICIPIO RRHH_MUNICIPIO { get; set; }
        public virtual SEG_ESTADO SEG_ESTADO { get; set; }



    }

Comment: Edita mejor tu pregunta y agrega este código. Para que sea más legible. Gracias